# Smooth animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, drawing, canvas

Is there a way to draw smooth animation in javascript?
In directx I'm using the vertical synchronisation. Can I achieve this in a html canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When drawing on a Canvas, I don't think there would be a vertical synchronization issue.

You should be more precise, and ask a more specific question about your problem (if any).